# Compilation error while compiling caffe on ubuntu

Tags: pytest, caffe, ubuntu-20.04, pycaffe

I tried to compile caffe on ubuntu 20.04 using cmake but it gives an error that 'The dependency target "pycaffe" of target "pytest" does not exist.'

I tried many times but it is giving error that 'The dependency target "pycaffe" of target "pytest" does not exist.'